How do we optimize a transaction-log VIEW in MySQL that will use a LIMIT when executed?
Problem / Observation
A query that performs well outside of a view (with a limit 20), uses a suboptimal query plan when placed inside of a view if the limit 20 is not included in the view definition but added to the view execution.
To be clear, if limit 20 is inside the view, the execution plan looks very good.  If we leave the limit 20 out of the view definition, but use it when we query the view, it uses a derived table that looks to me to be suboptimal.
Background
We have a transaction log that will grow very large.  For diagnostic purposes we periodically query the transaction log.
To facilitate the query, we've created a view that returns results in a more human-readable form with useful information.

Sometimes we just want 20 rows.  Sometimes we want 100 rows.
We always want the results in descending order by translog_id.

Question
What techniques can we use to have a variable limit on the view results but still have it perform well?
EXAMPLE Demonstrating the Problem
-- Simple translog query with LIMIT 20:
explain
select translog.translog_id,
    translog.transtype_code, 
    translog.target_id as target_id,
    translog.date_posted,
    translog.user_id appuser_userid,
    translog.details,
    GROUP_CONCAT( concat( auditlog.audit_col, "(", auditlog.oldval, "->", auditlog.newval, ")") SEPARATOR ", ") as audit_log
from translog 
left join auditlog on auditlog.translog_id = translog.translog_id
group by translog_id
order by translog_id desc
limit 20

RESULT:


Now, let's create a VIEW of that identical query, but leaving off the LIMIT 20 which we'll use later when querying the view.
-- VIEW doing the same thing but without the LIMIT 20 which will be applied at query execution
create or replace view opt as
select translog.translog_id,
    translog.transtype_code, 
    translog.target_id as target_id,
    translog.date_posted,
    translog.user_id appuser_userid,
    translog.details,
    GROUP_CONCAT( concat( auditlog.audit_col, "(", auditlog.oldval, "->", auditlog.newval, ")") SEPARATOR ", ") as audit_log
from translog 
left join auditlog on auditlog.translog_id = translog.translog_id
group by translog_id
order by translog_id desc;
-- limit 20

Let's look at the query execution plan when executing that view with LIMIT 20 added on
explain select * from opt limit 20


Note Not relevant, but wanted to add, I've simplified the query for this post -- our actual query joins a few more tables, but this here demonstrates the crux of my question/issue.
Executing the query returns the 20 rows:


Which version of MySQL?

group by translog_id is irrelevant since that column is (I assume) UNIQUE.  Please update the Question to get rid of that distraction.

You could try having LIMIT 100 always in the VIEW, while allowing the users to use LIMIT 20 when invoking the View.

@RickJames since the query involves GROUP_CONCAT for the left join's auditlog (where translog_id isn't unique on the audit table rows), I don't think that can be removed, ya?  If it were possible to keep that group_concat and remove the "group by" I think the optimizer issue would go away

I see that joining the view to a subset of key values appears to avoid the full table scan.  This could be a workaround.. but shouldn't be necessary if the optimizer worked as I think it ought.
e.g.
-- the following grabs the last 15 IDs and joins that to the view
-- essentially doing the same thing as "limit 15" with desc order
select * from opt myresults 
join
  ( select translog_id 
    from translog 
    order by translog_id desc limit 15) last15 
  on myresults.translog_id = last15.translog_id


This avoids the LEFT JOIN by folding the CONCAT into the SELECT.  It also gets rid of the GROUP BY:
select  t.translog_id,
        t.transtype_code,
        t.target_id AS target_id,
        t.date_posted, t.user_id AS appuser_userid,
        t.details,
        ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( concat( a.audit_col, "(", a.oldval,
                               "->", a.newval, ")" SEPARATOR ", " )
               FROM auditlog AS a WHERE a.translog_id = t.translog_id
        ) as audit_log
    from  translog AS t
    order by  translog_id desc;
    limit  20

I assume both tables have the PRIMARY KEY or other INDEX starting with translog_id.

This is fantastic.  by folding the CONCAT inside it seems to solve the optimization problem.  Only downside now is that if I choose to put a limit inside the view, it might produce wrong results if the where clause when executed would normally include rows that are outside of those # of rows.
e.g. if view has "LIMIT 200", and where on execution says "where auditlog is NOT NULL".  Table Rows outside the last 200 that are not null don't get returned.
But that's for another day.. thanks for the good idea to put in subquery
